# pacmd command run in local crontab does not work

Tags: ubuntu, cron, crontab, pulse-audio

I am trying to run certain commands at startup to allow my Audio to be FIFO Piped into a file.
If i run the commands (either manually or in a script) it works fine. However when i put them in my local crontab -e the commands throw errors.

One example command:

```
pacmd load-module module-pipe-sink file=/tmp/snapfifo/bt sink_name=Bluetooth format=s16le rate=48000
```

If I run this from crontab or as sudo I get:

Home directory not acessible
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

If I run this as sudo with my user (sudo -u USER) in only get this error:
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

I have been looking for solution for more than 5h on this, and tried loading environments, and user user PATHs but nothing helped. 
Hope somebody has an idea on how I can actually run the command automatically on startup.

Comment: read more about dbus and shell environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally:

Script needs the following reference:

> export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH="/run/user/$(id -u)/pulse/"

To check the correct path:

> echo ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}

Run the script with:

> sudo - u USERNAME -H